# Google client-side location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I will start with the code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(google.loader.ClientLocation){
    visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
    document.getElementById('location').value = visitor_city;
  }
</script>
```

In my case this code fails to produce the correct city at times. It some cases, it posts the correct city once, other times it posts the wrong city, and finally posts nothing at all. I need the city location to be correct in order to control access to my site so I can build a local following. The code was based on the information from [this site](http://briancray.com/posts/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/).

I would like to continue using Google Location services and I am wondering whether anyone else has the same issue. If so, did you come up with a better solution that worked much better?

Edit: I am located in Ottawa, Ontario, Canada, so internet access or geolocation should not be an issue as I am not out in the boonies.

Comment: Note that it's not allowed according to Google TOS to use geoloaction without also showing a Google map.

Comment: alright can you suggest some other service?

Comment: I'm just going to ask the user. I store their answer in a cookie or something and go from there.